# How to write properly math accent for letter i?

Tags: math-mode, accents, characters

When it is requested to write letter "`í`" in math mode, it happens that `$\acute{i}$` is not the right answer as it could be expected: the accent (`´`) is written over the letter (`i`), without deleting/overwriting the upper dot `(^{.})` Another possiblity to solve the problem: `$\acute{\imath}$`, not always works satisfactorily. Is there another way to do it, obtaining an acceptable/appropriate character?

Comment: While I don’t recommend it, `\mathalpha{\textit{\acute{i}}}` is another way.

Answer (score 19):

`$\acute{\imath}$` is the right way. What do you mean by "not always works satisfactorily"?

In general, `\imath` and its companion `\jmath` should be used for the math accents:

- `\acute{\imath}`
- `\grave{\imath}`
- `\dot{\imath}` (ambiguous!)
- `\ddot{\imath}`

and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69373/#comment148505_69374

\begin{document}
  $\imath$ $\acute{\imath}$ $\acute{i}$ $\grave{\imath}$ $\dot{\imath}$ $i$ $\ddot{\imath}$
  
  $\jmath$ $\acute{\jmath}$ $\acute{j}$ $\grave{\jmath}$ $\dot{\jmath}$ $j$ $\ddot{\jmath}$
  
  $X_{\mathrm{s\acute\imath}}$ $X_{\textup{s\'i}}$ $X_{\textup{sí}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between your suggestion and those one wrote on the question?

Comment: Well, what I want to say is the next: when you have the expression $X_{\rm s\acute\imath}$, the grammar is more or less ok, but not completely correct, because the second letter is not in \rm. Is it feasible to write completly the subscript in normal text (e.g. roman)?

Comment: @paritto If you need a textual subscript, use `$X_{\textup{s\`i}}$` or `$X_{\textup{sì}}$` (if you are using `inputenc`); this needs the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @egrep: Just `\text` as I know. When using `\textup`, `amsmath` is not needed.

Comment: @LeoLiu With `amsmath`, `\textup` will take care of the size in a subscript; without the package it wouldn't. With `\text` the *current* font will be used, with `\textup` the upright shape will certainly be selected.

Comment: The post already solved my doubt at all.